# React mapping objects, targeting errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, array.prototype.map

I have some troubles mapping fetched objects, i know it's a known problem but it's been two days i'm stuck so i come asking for some help.

I'm trying to output data on an ul from an api but i either have errors or nothing gets output, i know that i am targeting my data inside my object the wrong way, it's the first time i'm trying to target an object with this kind of keys

I have an object 'names' looking like that:

[image]

```
[Array(20)]
  0: Array(20)
    0:
      avatar: ""
      country: "RU"
      games: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
      nickname: "d2mash"
      player_id: "07982364-a458-4a1f-b6d6-1be146db9126"
      status: "AVAILABLE"
      verified: true
      __proto__: Object
    1: {player_id: "cab2a609-de2f-4023-a9c7-af89d5292c96", nickname: "D0cC-", status: "BUSY", games: Array(1), country: "NL", …}
    2: {player_id: "d67a944f-1c1d-4d75-a7bf-d52c4b30e7db", nickname: "r1d3Rz", status: "AVAILABLE", games: Array(1), country: "RO", …}
    3: {player_id: "f40bef0d-d40a-48d0-8c53-5a513c35bd3a", nickname: "dotademon", status: "AVAILABLE", games: Array(1), country: "US", …}
    4: {player_id: "dca784fa-546b-43b7-adf6-cf537d858d4f", nickname: "degeneral", status: "AVAILABLE", games: Array(2), country: "UA", …}
    5: {player_id: "e72a43cd-d214-4d4c-989a-efb1d3e7df37", nickname: "daave-", status: "AVAILABLE", games: Array(1), country: "US", …}
    6: {player_id: "4e093c2c-f277-4877-a200-029ae6d8602f", nickname: "ddk", status: "AVAILABLE", games: Array(5), country: "US", …}
    7: {player_id: "ef629874-bf6e-4066-8612-09e0428e923c", nickname: "dieZzz", status: "AVAILABLE", games: Array(3), country: "RU", …}
    8: {player_id: "77995857-d14d-47ed-a150-4f175f70654e", nickname: "durpdurp", status: "AVAILABLE", games: Array(1), country: "US", …}
    9: {player_id: "e3ed56b6-138f-4141-b6c9-ba6eab7bfc24", nickname: "dengue", status: "AVAILABLE", games: Array(3), country: "PT", …}
    10: {player_id: "d6bd0d6f-a068-4e10-b9a4-129297c8691f", nickname: "disco doplan", status: "BUSY", games: Array(2), country: "SE", …}
    11: {player_id: "7e80ed2a-8e39-457e-95c2-1c9ba9449daf", nickname: "dupreeh", status: "BUSY", games: Array(1), country: "DK", …}
    12: {player_id: "32772d2f-fb63-4a84-ac06-4c2e20f49082", nickname: "denis-", status: "AVAILABLE", games: Array(1), country: "DE", …}
    13: {player_id: "089df523-86dd-4705-944f-f012adb5a0f8", nickname: "dream3r---", status: "AVAILABLE", games: Array(1), country: "BG", …}
    14: {player_id: "b8b709e5-96f8-4cf5-8348-95b8b67e0b34", nickname: "DreadAV", status: "AVAILABLE", games: Array(1), country: "RU", …}
    15: {player_id: "5fd703b0-6762-44c8-9284-b8f01ef70e71", nickname: "DendiGoD", status: "AVAILABLE", games: Array(1), country: "UA", …}
    16: {player_id: "6c4f1a76-1341-4513-90ac-8d43dd1c86b6", nickname: "dipparn", status: "AVAILABLE", games: Array(1), country: "SE", …}
    17: {player_id: "ae0bfe74-ec96-4499-910f-e02acd5be700", nickname: "DuBu-", status: "AVAILABLE", games: Array(1), country: "CA", …}
    18: {player_id: "d6bc4849-5256-4463-a38e-bcd77fc31ff9", nickname: "device", status: "BUSY", games: Array(1), country: "DK", …}
    19: {player_id: "4bb4503f-5272-40dc-8165-d050290db66a", nickname: "desi", status: "AVAILABLE", games: Array(1), country: "US", …}
    length: 20
    __proto__: Array(0)
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

Then i pass it to a component like that:

```
{
    !isLoading && 
    <PlayerSearchResult players={names} />
}
```

My component:

```
class PlayerSearchItem extends Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <li key={this.props.cle}>
        <Link to={"#"}>nom - {this.props.pseudo}</Link>
      </li>
    );
  }
}

class PlayerSearchResult extends Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {Object.keys(this.props.players).map((player, i) => (
            <PlayerSearchItem
              cle={player[player].player_id}
              pseudo={players[i]}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

don't mind the way I'm targeting my data, it's one of my many tries.

Comment: would you mind to copy and paste your data here instead of adding screenshots? It would help people to debug your issue and provide you better answers

Comment: Probably not the bug you search for but cle={player[player].player_id} 's player[player] part looks like you are using incorrect key for the player object, maybe change it to just player.player_id, or players[player]. player_id

Answer (score 1):

I think that your map looks wrong

This:

```
Object.keys(this.props.players).map((player, i) => ( <
  PlayerSearchItem cle = {
    player[player].player_id
  }
  pseudo = {
    players[i]
  }
  />
))
```

Should be:

```
Object.keys(this.props.players).map((player, i) => ( <
  PlayerSearchItem cle = {
    player.player_id
  }
  pseudo = {
    player
  }
  key={player.player_id}
  />
))
```

Then from the screenshot of your data, it looks like you have as data an array of 20 items, which has as first element an array of 20 items, where the items from 1 to 20 are the real players.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i tried it, i have an ouput of "0" (a key a guess) and it doesnt map because i have dont have 20 items, i only have one that gets displayed.

Comment: I think you should pass `<PlayerSearchResult players={names[0].slice(1)} />` looking to the screenshot, but pay attention to your data and avoid screenshots here please, paste the code, that's easy to copy and paste, to read, and to debug

Comment: I've updated my post, hope it's what you expeted, when i dot that i have 'Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined' and when i dont slice it i get 'Cannot convert undefined or null to object' i guess names[0] is undefined wich shoudnt be